# Solabegron and antimuscarinic patent?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [EP2600859A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2600859A1)

Has this patent been granted?

Does it mean that 1. all combination therapy consisting of beta-3 agonists in combination with muscarinic agonists have been patented by AltheRx OR just 
2. Solabegron in combination with muscarinic agonists have been patented by AltheRx?

Answer (score 1):

As of May 12, 2018, according to the EP Registry, it is still under examination. The US version of this application was granted on February 4th, 2014 as [US864661B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8642661B2/en).

What is covered is defined by the claims. Here is the first claim of the US patent:

> 1. A combination comprising:
>
>    (i) a therapeutically effective amount of a beta-3 adrenergic receptor agonist selected from the group
>      consisting of solabegron and pharmaceutically acceptable salts
>      thereof; and
>
>    (ii) a therapeutically effective amount, or a
>      sub-therapeutically effective amount, of a muscarinic receptor
>      antagonist selected from the group consisting of tolterodine,
>      oxybutynin, trospium, solifenacin, darifenacin, propiverine,
>      fesoterodine, and pharmaceutically acceptable salts thereof,
>
>    said
>      combination being useful for relieving one or more symptoms of
>      overactive bladder in a synergistic manner, versus the individual
>      components (i) and (ii), wherein said one or more symptoms of
>      overactive bladder are selected from the group consisting of frequency
>      of urgency, nocturia, increase in urinary micturition frequency, and
>      urinary incontinence

As you can see, the muscarinic receptor antagonist is specified from a group of seven compounds and salts thereof.

The claims in the US version may not be the same as other versions of this patent so if they get granted you will need to review those separately to see what is covered.

Answer (score 0):

Patent has not been granted, currently its under examination. Check Status using [STATUS](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP11748801)

you can check the amended claim using EP register **All documents**

Answer (score 0):

The amended claims were filed in April 2016. Currently, the pace of work in the EPO results in examiners replying in about 6 months, so check again the EP Registry (all documents tab) for the examiners reply around October. You can also create a personal account (Register Alert) and add this application to your monitoring list. The EPO then sents notification emails about changes of the application status (sometimes with a few days delay, but it is a useful tool).